# PyQt: Unstack push buttons after using hide and show

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a group box that I have buttons arranged in a vertical format. See image below. The red background indicates which index of my stacked widget is active, just ignore it.

Button Arrangement

[image]

When I use the .hide() method, the button hides, great.

However, when I use the .show() method on the button, it will not return. I assume it is being placed under the other push button and I can't access the button. See image below.

Broken Button Arrangement

[image]

I have tried using the .adjustSize(), .repaint() and .update() methods on the group box, however it doesn't correct the issue.

I should mention in the group box, I do have a vertical spacer, that has a sizeType of 'Expanding' that is pushing the buttons up.

**Question:**
How do I get the buttons to show and spread out again as the first image when I use the .show() method?

Per Request, adding in sample code. Please keep in mind this is about as minimal as I can make it.

appui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_app(object):
    def setupUi(self, app):
        app.setObjectName("App")
        app.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        app.resize(400, 852)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(app.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        app.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        app.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 0))
        app.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 16777215))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        app.setFont(font)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/app.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        app.setWindowIcon(icon)
        app.setStyleSheet("")        
        self.groupbox_buttongroup = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tabWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.groupbox_buttongroup.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 0))
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setStyleSheet("")
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setTitle("")
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setFlat(True)
        self.groupbox_buttongroup.setObjectName("groupbox_buttongroup")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn_notefield = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_notefield.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_notefield.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_notefield.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.btn_notefield.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.btn_notefield.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_notes.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_notefield.setIcon(icon2)
        self.btn_notefield.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_notefield.setObjectName("btn_notefield")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_notefield)
        self.btn_nuc = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.btn_nuc.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_nuc.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_nuc.setIcon(icon3)
        self.btn_nuc.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_nuc.setObjectName("btn_nuc")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_nuc)
        self.btn_com = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.btn_com.setText("")
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_com.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_com.setIcon(icon4)
        self.btn_com.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_com.setObjectName("btn_com")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_com)
        self.btn_comcontacts = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.btn_comcontacts.setText("")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_contacts.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_comcontacts.setIcon(icon5)
        self.btn_comcontacts.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_comcontacts.setObjectName("btn_comcontacts")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_comcontacts)
        self.btn_nucsearch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.btn_nucsearch.setText("")
        icon6 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon6.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_search.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_nucsearch.setIcon(icon6)
        self.btn_nucsearch.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_nucsearch.setObjectName("btn_nucsearch")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_nucsearch)
        self.btn_about = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupbox_buttongroup)
        self.btn_about.setText("")
        icon7 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon7.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("theme/g_about.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.btn_about.setIcon(icon7)
        self.btn_about.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 30))
        self.btn_about.setObjectName("btn_about")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_about)
        spacerItem38 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem38)
```

appmain.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from appui import Ui_app
from settingsui import Ui_Settings

class appMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_app):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.btn_notefield.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
        self.btn_notefield.released.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.btn_com.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(2))
        self.btn_com.released.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.btn_comcontacts.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(3))
        self.btn_comcontacts.released.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.btn_nuc.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.btn_nuc.released.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.btn_nucsearch.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(4))
        self.btn_nucsearch.released.connect(self.updateButton)
        self.btn_about.released.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(5))
        self.btn_about.released.connect(self.updateButton)

    def settings(self):

        app = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.settingui = settingsui()
        self.settingui.btn_profileapply.clicked.connect(self.applyprofile)


    def applyprofile(self):


        if self.settingui.radiobtn_custom.isChecked():
            user = os.getenv('username')

            custom_opts = []

            tabopts = [
            self.settingui.checkbox_nuctab,
            self.settingui.checkbox_comtab,
            self.settingui.checkbox_nucomcontact,
            self.settingui.checkbox_nucsearch,
            ]

            for option in tabopts:
                if option.isChecked():
                    selected_opt = option.text()
                    custom_opts.append(selected_opt)

            with open(f'C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\app\\settings', 'r') as rsettings:
                sett = json.load(rsettings)

            sett['default_profile']['profile'] = 'custom'
            sett['custom_opts']['selected_opts'] = custom_opts

            with open(f'C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\app\\settings', 'w') as wsettings:
                json.dump(sett, wsettings, indent=2)

            for item in custom_opts:
                if item == 'COM Tab':
                    self.btn_com.show()

                if item != 'COM Tab':
                    self.btn_com.hide()

                if item == 'nuc Tab':
                    self.btn_nuc.show()

                if item != 'nuc Tab':
                    self.btn_nuc.hide()

                if item == 'NUC/COM Contacts':
                    self.btn_comcontacts.show()

                if item != 'NUC/COM Contacts':
                    self.btn_comcontacts.hide()

                if item == 'NUC Search':
                    self.btn_nucsearch.show()

                if item != 'NUC Search':
                    self.btn_nucsearch.hide()

class settingsui(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Settings):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = appMain()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sample code provided. This is about as minimal as I can provide. Hope it helps.

Comment: your code is not complete since there are a lot of things to define in both files so I can not reproduce the error, and I can not help you

Comment: Ok, thanks for stopping by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. The if statement to show the btn, was being ignored, because it was after json dumped the data back to the file.